# Should exceptions thrown from class member initializers call std::terminate()?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, compiler-bug

Given this code:

```cpp
struct A {
    A(int e) { throw e; }
};

struct B {
    A a{42}; // Same with = 42; syntax
};

int main() {
    try {
        B b;
    } catch (int const e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

When compiled with GCC (versions 4.7.4, 4.8.5, 4.9.3, 5.4.0, 6.3.0):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test; ./test ; echo $?
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Aborted
134
```

But when compiled with Clang (version 4.0.0):

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test; ./test ; echo $?
42
```

Which behavior is correct?

Comment: Clang is correct.

Comment: Ah yes! Probably same issue as in GCC [PR 80683](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80683).

Comment: Anyone else read the title as "is this a good design pattern" initially?  ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC ([Bug 80683](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80683)).

If the constructor is the first op in the `try/catch` clause, then the compiler considered it as being outside of it although it should include it.

For example, the following works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int e) { throw e; }
};

struct B {
    A a{42}; // Same with = 42; syntax
};

int main() {
    try {
        // The following forces the compiler to put B's contructor inside the try/catch.
        std::cout << "Welcome" << std::endl; 
        B b;
    } catch (int e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << e << std::endl; // This is just for debugging
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -DNDEBUG -o test; ./test ; echo $?
```

Outputs:

```
Welcome
ERROR: 42
0
```

My guess is that is that due to compiler optimization, it moves the constructor to the beginning of the main function. It assumes that the `struct B` has no constructor, then it assumes that it would never throw an exception, thus it is safe to move it outside of the `try/catch` clause.

If we will change the declaration of `struct B` to **explicitly** use `struct A` constructor:

```
struct B {
    B():a(42) {}
    A a;
};
```

Then the result will be as expected and we will enter the `try/catch`, even when removing the "Welcome" printout:

```
ERROR: 42
0
```

Comment: Funny (gcc (Gentoo 6.4.0-r1 p1.3) 6.4.0): ```$ g++ so-43892186.cpp -o so-43892186 && ./so-43892186``` --- ```Welcome``` --- ```terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'```

Comment: @BodoThiesen I guess that some compilers allow reorders to cross IO instructions and some don't'.

Answer (score 4):

Clang is correct. References about that can be found in C++ standard reference draft n4296 (emphasize mine):

> 15.3 Handling an exception [except.handle]
>
> ...
> 3 A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
> (3.1) — The handler is of type cv T or cv T& and E and T are the same type (**ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers**),

Here an `int` is thrown, and the handler declares a `const int`. There is a match and the handler shall be invoked.